# Silverstripe & ReCaptcha formatting

Tags: recaptcha, silverstripe

I have a recapture form field added through userforms module for Silverstripe. And if you look at http://www.ct.com.au/contact you will see the captcha form looks quite messy.

Using Chrome debugger I noticed that the captcha is adding an extra `<tr>` field and I've looked everywhere and have no idea how to get rid of it.

Please help!

Comment: seems like @3dgoo answered your question satisfactorily, so please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'MathSpamProtection' not found in /var/www/html/centorrino/spamprotection/code/EditableSpamProtectionField.php on line 19 I get this error when i try to install math spam protection, I use the following: SpamProtectorManager::set_spam_protector('MathSpamProtection');

Answer (score 1):

The reason it looks so messy is the height of the captcha input that it inherits from your page css pushes out the box height. We need to reset the height of this input field.

Add the following to your css:

```css
.recaptchatable #recaptcha_response_field {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: hi which file do i add this to? page.ss or contactpage.ss

Comment: Hi @David. This code goes in one of your site css files. In this case that would be `themes/centorrino/css/style.css`

Comment: No. This is how [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) functions. You can look at using alternative spam protection like [Math Spam Protection](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-mathspamprotection) or [Mollom](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-mollom).

Comment: I can't use math protection with spam protection module can I?

Comment: Yes. Math Spam Protection uses and requires the Spam Protection module to operate.

Comment: okay I will try it, tried Mollom and got an error class Mollom not found so reverted back to recaptcha

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'MathSpamProtection' not found in /var/www/html/centorrino/spamprotection/code/EditableSpamProtectionField.php on line 19  I get this error when i try to install math spam protection, I use the following: SpamProtectorManager::set_spam_protector('MathSpamProtection');

Comment: Make sure you call `?flush=all`

Comment: where would I call that?

Comment: Put that on the end of your website URL in the address bar. Or any page really. Flushing is covered in the first silverstripe tutorial: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/1-building-a-basic-site#templates If you haven't gone through them they are well worth a look.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'MathSpamProtection' not found in /var/www/html/centorrino/spamprotection/code/EditableSpamProtectionField.php on line 19  same error even after I flush

Comment: Make sure your mathspamprotection module folder is named mathspamprotection as per the [installation documentation](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-mathspamprotection/blob/master/docs/en/Installing.md).